# How can I get names of uninitialized static properties in a class before ESNext?

Tags: typescript

I have a typescript class with several static properties leave `uninitialized` such as:

```js
class A {
    static foo:number
    static bar:number
}

for(const key in A) {
    console.log(key)
}
```

If I compile this code in target `ESNext` everything is fine and all the keys would be logged.

However, if I change the target to any previous, even `ES2020`, I will get an empty output.

When I dig into the generated javascript code I could see all the properties had been removed:

```
"use strict";
class A {
}
for (const key in A) {
    console.log(key);
}
```

How can I keep these properties before ESNext?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48907438/typescript-get-uninitialized-properties-after-compilation

Comment: @captain-yossarian. I know that an intial value or a decorator could keep these fields but I'm looking for a way without both of them. But this won't bother me any more since I've update my v8 engine to the latest which full supports the esnext features and I can use esnext whitout worries.

Comment: Btw, how did you update v8 engine? By updating nodejs? or you have some specific env?

Comment: Yes. I used v8 with a UE plugin: https://github.com/Tencent/puerts/blob/master/doc/en/README.md

Comment: Holly sh*t :))) This is far beyond my knowledge

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the answer to your question is likely 'no'.

Typescript can [useDefineForClassFields](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#useDefineForClassFields), which I think is currently correct for esnext in this case (src: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/43113).

But es2021 still does not have static fields. src: https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields -- they are stage 3 (at least according to that proposal page).

reproduction of your issue: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?module=5&ts=4.3.4#code/MYGwhgzhAECC0G8BQ1XQgFzBglsaAZgPZEBcAdgK4C2ARgKYBOA3CmptntLWIxTQxZIAvkiTAi5CERD0AdCCIBzABQByAA6MiGImoA00APK0AVvWAY5S+hiMB3cgAVtGphgCeAEXoRgjHA1dRggVWDktHR0PNwBKWLFiRhUJKQxoAGt6D2gccjhYxDZUVOlZBWUVLI8E4SA

Note that you can get close with `static #foo`, and in a way closer with `static ##foo` .. but neither of these will execute in the target context ("private fields are not currently supported"). This is just abusing the ongoing partial/increasing support for class fields and private fields.

Answer (score 0):

Just assign static property to some initialize value

```
class A {
    static foo:number = 1
    static bar:number = 2
}
```

[PlaygroundLink](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?module=6&noErrorTruncation=false#code/FAYwNghgzlAECCsDexZtlALhTBLEsAZgPbEBcAdgK4C2ARgKYBOsAvLAIyrpY76x0ITSrUYt2AJmABfYHOAkmAChDEKWWAGsGAT1i4KCAJTJuaVeuJgGAOjDEA5ku06jMuQBMGdKg4fM5IA) on ES2015

Comment: I'd like to leave these fields `uninitialized` since I'm going to init them with a class decorator later.

Comment: Ok you can initialize in your decorator  too and there is nothing wrong with it.

Comment: The reason that `ts` compiler remove property is not `static` is about that `ts` compiler remove anything that has undefined value.  For sure you can take the `static` from `foo and bar` and still does not show in `console` . [PlaygroundLik](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?module=6&strict=false&noErrorTruncation=false#code/FAYwNghgzlAECCsDexZtgMwPZYFwDsBXAWwCMBTAJwG5V1SJKCSKbg60Qt8oAXSwiF5ZKACgD62PLCJkqAGljiGTGSyoBKFOh2xeACwCWUAHRTYAXiVTau9AeMmVlpSo6wAvuy-BsYrjy8sADW5ACesIb4CBrI7gFQWGDkJmBYAOaioWEawD7AQA)

Comment: I was talking about the tsc removes the `static` fields before esnext not the instance fields.  I just want find a way to make tsc `not to remove the static fields` even before esnext.

Answer (score 0):

You should explicitly set your properties to `undefined` (or `null` if you prefer):

```
class A {
  static foo: number | undefined = undefined; // same as uninitialzied value
  static bar: number | undefined = undefined;
}
```

**Reasoning**: In addition to preserving your properties after compilation, this is a more accurate type-definition *if you are not initializing your property*. As long as you declare a variable or property without initialization (e.g. `let a: number;`), you create a situation where that variable or property could be used before initialization and therefore its value will be `undefined`:

```
class A {
    static foo: number // will be `undefined` until initialization.
    static bar: number | undefined = undefined;
}

A.foo.toString() // No compiler error, but fails at runtime. Bad!
A.bar.toString() // Produces a compiler error. Good!
```

If you don't want to deal with `undefined` or `null` values, you should initialize your class variables to satisfy the `number` type constraint:

```
class A {
  static foo: number = 0;
  static bar: number = 0;
}
```

[Full Playground Example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECC0G8CwAoa7oQC5iwS2GgDMB7EgLmgDsBXAWwCMBTAJ1Q0x30IbBctqNWqAL6pUsAHSkSkrCQDKWFnioBzABQBKaAHpd0AAosSAExrAmMMNBY0q%20Ok2isTLAITQARAGEwVKhIsWyYwU2gABxMI1iwAT2gAcnklFXVE6BIiaHtTJiJVJlMvcRRSFmgNYBIqbGgAayYE1TgdZDQMatqSECZJEBJNRritUVLQSBgAIUR2DGxcAmIyAXpmCoAfHKo8gqoi6ABebd3C0wBuOfQF7mhefmo11mgt3Pyzo5P3-YuxlFQptIyHJFMpVJodPojCZzJZrNBqnQInhehVXCQWJJoABZCwACzuTCwWFYkiAA)